# How to remove an embedded audio using JQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to remove an embedded audio after some x seconds in web page using JQuery or JavaScript

```
     <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var interval = 46000;
    setTimeout(function () {

       $("#srcaudio").remove();

        setTimeout(arguments.callee, interval);
    }, interval);
});
</script><div id="preloader"> 
    <img class="logo" src="images/prelogo.gif" width="190" height="176">
     <h2>"content........... 
    ".</h2>
    <div id="srcaudio">
    <embed src="src/preloadtheme.mp3" hidden="true"></embed></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add id to  instead of div.
it will work.

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    var interval = 2000;
    setTimeout(function () {

       $("#srcaudio").remove();

        setTimeout(arguments.callee, interval);
    }, interval);

});
```